# PostgreSQL data not showing in Docker Container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I need some help, I'm stuck in Docker and can't find it out. I'm using Windows for a Django APP and Docker

I'm using PgAdmin4 with PostgreSQL 16 and created a new server for docker

The log for the Postgres Image:

```
 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

 2023-11-23 20:17:38.008 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
 2023-11-23 20:17:38.008 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
 2023-11-23 20:17:38.008 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
 2023-11-23 20:17:38.027 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
 2023-11-23 20:17:38.086 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-23 20:17:11 UTC
 2023-11-23 20:17:39.317 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Logs from my web:

```
No changes detected
Operations to perform:
   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, base, contenttypes, sessions
 Running migrations:
   No migrations to apply.
 Watching for file changes with StatReloader
 Performing system checks...
 
 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
 November 23, 2023 - 20:17:44
 Django version 4.2.2, using settings 'cutler.settings'
 Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
 Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "sleep 5 && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

setting.py file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

So, analyzing the logs from Postgres last line, he found my local DB and didn't initialize, but my superuser is gone and so my data.

Here is screenshot from my db(it has data inside):
[db screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7TpK.jpg)

Here is screenshot from my app, here must be all products from database, but it's empty:
[app screenshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwPvl.jpg)

I hope someone can help me.

I just want to solve this and move forward :)

Comment: Simplest thing to check first: are you sure your ./data/db directory still exists and you didn't change it?  Other things: are you sure your db name is still the same? it's an env variable and it would be an easy mistake to have it be different from one run to the next

Take a careful look through the startup output from your db container.  You will either see something about "creating a new database" or "using existing database".  That will give you some clues too

Comment: 1. yeah, ./data/db still exist, i didn't touch this file since it was created
2. my db name should be the same, i initialized it in my .env file or maybe i'm thinking wrong
@BillHuneke

Comment: And, just checking here, you've got your Python / Django code set up to read from the .env file? You probably already realize this, but Django doesn't care about a .env file natively (as far as I know).  Again, just covering the basics here first :)

Comment: The startup messages you show in the question look fine.  What's the actual problem you're running into?  (Make sure to include your containers' output as plain text and not images, and directly in the question and not behind links.)

Comment: I have some data in database(like accounts, products etc.) and when i start project via docker i cant use this data(can't login to django admin e.g.) p.s can't add images without links, i need 10 reputation :) @DavidMaze

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).